# How to draw line with same length on all devices?

Tags: html, css, drawing, resolution

On an HTML page, I want to draw a line of defined length, say 5cm. The line should be always exactly 5cm,

- on each type of display,
- regardless of physical monitor size
- with each monitor resolution selected
- with any screen scaling selected
- which each browser zoom level

I found one way to do this, but this needs calibration by the user: Show some scalable line, let the user put a bank card (which length is known) next to it, let the user resize the line until it fits the card length, and calculate the perfect ratio.

But how can I get a result without user action?

The easiest way, I thought, was to use 'cm' in the CSS. Nope. One 'cm' is 4mm on my smartphone, but 12mm on my monitor.

I've tried dividing by window.devicePixelRatio. This works with some 20% error on a modern monitor, set to the suggested resolution. The length stays the same when I change the browser zoom and refresh. It does not work on my smartphone, where I get much smaller lengths, and the results differ between landscape and portrait. This does not work when I set my monitor resolution to lower values. And it does not work if I compare a 24" and a 27" monitor with the same resolution.

I'd like to accomplish this using html/css/javascript in a browser (and maybe openlayers).

Comment: More info on the absolute units in CSS : https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/07/css-absolute-units/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that's one of the hardest things to do.  There is an unit `cm` in CSS as well as `mm`, but they are actually directly converted from the pixel value : `1 cm = 37.795 px`. Pixel value which is itself relative on each display.

For using the centimeters unit, you could write:

```html
<div id="line-5cm"></div>

<style>
#line-5cm{
  height: 4px;
  width: 5cm;
  background-color: black;
}
</style>
```

I tried it, and a `div` with `width: 10cm;` was measuring `10.1cm` So that's seems pretty accurate. But I am quite sure on some devices it will not work.

Another option you may want to play with is the meta `viewport` in the `head`:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

Try to change the values and see if it can improve the accuracy.

More informations :

- https://medium.com/level-up-web/the-difference-between-css-units-px-pt-rem-em-vh-vw-ch-ex-and-the-rest-b2cfdf069230
- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/07/css-absolute-units/

Comment: Thank you, but, as I wrote, this was the first thing I tried. On my monitor 1cm  results in 1.2cm on my monitor, 4mm on my mobile.

Comment: I see.. Did you setup the meta `viewport` ? 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">`

Comment: I didn't. Now I've done it. On the monitor the result stays exactly the same ('5cm'->7cm), on the mobile the line got a little longer, but not enough ('5cm'->3cm).

Comment: Try maybe to combine this with the `window.devicePixelRatio` method ?

Comment: I tried to. the lines get a little smaller, but too long on my monitor anyway. '5cm' -> 6cm.

Comment: This is the - really accurate - method, I mentioned: 
https://www.ginifab.com/feeds/cm_to_inch/actual_size_ruler.html